# uikit 3.0 - responsive grid for mobile

Tags: html, css, web, uikit, responsive

i'm currently playing with the uikit (https://getuikit.com). 
I'm in trouble creating a responsive grid. For desktop & mobile.

My html is looking like this:

```
<div class="uk-section uk-section-muted">
<div class="uk-container uk-position-relative">
    <h1 class="uk-h1 uk-heading-line uk-text-center uk-text-lowercase"><span>hey</span></h1>
    <div class="uk-grid-match uk-child-width-1-3@m" uk-grid>
        <div>
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-large uk-card-hover uk-card-body uk-responsive-width">
                <h3 class="uk-card-title uk-text-lowercase">lorem</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                    labore
                    et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-large uk-card-hover uk-card-body uk-responsive-width">
                <h3 class="uk-card-title uk-text-lowercase">lorem</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                    labore
                    et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-large uk-card-hover uk-card-body uk-responsive-width">
                <h3 class="uk-card-title uk-text-lowercase">lorem</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                    labore
                    et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and it looks good for the desktop browser, but not when it comes to mobile. 
The mobile version looks like this:
https://prnt.sc/jet3f3

And it should look like this:
http://prntscr.com/jet47e

Thanks for your support,

cheers

Answer (score 0):

All you was missing to include the js file

```
<script src="https://getuikit.com/assets/uikit/dist/js/uikit.js"></script>
```

and also make sure your HTML inside `<head>` tag contain

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and here is a codepen with a test 
https://codepen.io/AElkhodary/pen/rvYGjo?editors=1010

and also you can check the code down

that's how it looks in responsive behavior [image]

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.42/css/uikit.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://getuikit.com/assets/uikit/dist/js/uikit.js"></script>
<div class="uk-section uk-section-muted">
<div class="uk-container uk-position-relative">
    <h1 class="uk-h1 uk-heading-line uk-text-center uk-text-lowercase"><span>hey</span></h1>
    <div class="uk-grid-match uk-child-width-1-3@m" uk-grid>
        <div>
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-large uk-card-hover uk-card-body uk-responsive-width">
                <h3 class="uk-card-title uk-text-lowercase">lorem</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                    labore
                    et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-large uk-card-hover uk-card-body uk-responsive-width">
                <h3 class="uk-card-title uk-text-lowercase">lorem</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                    labore
                    et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-large uk-card-hover uk-card-body uk-responsive-width">
                <h3 class="uk-card-title uk-text-lowercase">lorem</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                    labore
                    et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I included js & css. I didnt added that in my question, sorry. Also in codepen, it looks not very responsive. Its looks like my screenshot.

Comment: I am sure you are trying it i a different way you have to open codepen and click on view then full page then go to mobile view because codepen if you resize the screen it wont show that its responsive try this even here in the code snippet that i provided in mobile view

Comment: and here from my phone https://prnt.sc/jeuy3b am sure man its responsive and you should try out in your local server or your page maybe you're missing something make sure you have   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
in your html file